# Error in code snippet in documentation - Cannot refer to non-final variable

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I'm working on Android application using Parse.com as the back-end.

The documentation of Parse's Android SDK contains following code in the [section related to the Local datastore feature](https://www.parse.com/docs/android_guide#localdatastore):

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("GameScore");
query.orderByDescending("score");

// Query for new results from the network.
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
    public void done(List<ParseObject> scores, ParseException e) {
        // Remove the previously cached results.
        ParseObject.unpinAllInBackground("highScores", new DeleteCallback() {
            public void done(ParseException e) {
                // Cache the new results.
                ParseObject.pinAllInBackground("highScores", scores);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

However, if I tried to use this in my code, I got error saying

> Cannot refer to a non-final variable scores inside an inner class
>   defined in a different method

on the line `ParseObject.pinAllInBackground("highScores", scores);`

I understand what the problem might be, the question is how to solve it.

### My ideas

1. By creating local final variable in the done method e.g. `final List<ParseObject> localScores = scores` and then use this in `pinAllInBackground`
2. By changing the signature of the `done` method to `public void done(`**final**`List<ParseObject> scores, ParseException e)`

Both options seem to work.

I'd like to get answer from experienced Java developers if one option is better than the other and why?

Personally I was surprised that option 2. worked, but it seems that the `final` modifier doesn't causes method overloading - here my missing deeper knowledge of Java is well demonstrated :-)

P.S. Let's keep aside the fact that official documentation contains non-working code snippets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would prefer option 2, since it saves you a variable declaration.

A `final` parameter does not change the signature of the method as seen from the caller (the signature is defined *only* by the name of the method and the types of its formal parameters, see [specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.2)). It's only for the implementation of said method, and it means that the variable cannot be assigned a new value.

It's necessary for use in anonymous inner classes because Java does not support closures.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I knew I heard something about this at university long time ago :-)